# UWP Canvas drawing out of bounds

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp

I have a canvas (not InkCanvas!) and I am able to draw Polylines on it. This is working just fine but there is a huge problem with drawing out of bounds like shown in the GIF below.

[image: Right side is the canvas, left side is empty space.]

My canvas is inside a ScrollViewer and the ScrollViewer is inside a GridView.

I tried to catch the pointer leaving the canvas with the following event handlers:

```
canvas.PointerExited += Canvas_PointerExited;
canvas.PointerCaptureLost += Canvas_PointerCaptureLost;
```

But it seems those events are fired way too slow.

I tried to use the Clip property of my canvas but there is no change in behaviour. And there is no "ClipToBound" property for the UWP canvas.

My whole view is generated in Code-Behind because I have to generate multiple canvases on one view.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

**EDIT1:**

As requested: more insight of my code.

The XAML Page looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="BoundingGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="InkGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Grid x:Name="CanvasGrid" Grid.Row="1" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

It's all inside a Page.

My code behind looks like this:

My constructors:

```
public ImprovedCanvasManager(Grid boundingGrid, Grid overviewGrid, string filepath, double height)
    {
        drawCanvas = new Canvas();

        overviewGrid.Loaded += OverviewGrid_Loaded;
        overviewGrid.SizeChanged += OverviewGrid_SizeChanged;

        RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();
        rd.Height = new GridLength(height);

        overviewGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);

        InitializeScrollViewer();

        Grid.SetRow(scroll, overviewGrid.RowDefinitions.Count);
        Grid.SetColumn(scroll, 0);

        scroll.Content = drawCanvas;
        overviewGrid.Children.Add(scroll);
        LoadImage(filepath);
    }

        public ImprovedCanvasManager(Grid boundingGrid, Grid overviewGrid, Grid inkToolGrid, string filepath, double height = 1000) : this(boundingGrid, overviewGrid, filepath, height)
    {
        AddDrawingToolsToCanvas(inkToolGrid, overviewGrid);
        EnableDrawingOnCanvas(drawCanvas);
    }
```

I only got two contructors to make it simple for me to instantiate canvases with the ability to draw and without the ability to draw.

This is how i initialise my ScrollViewer:

```
private void InitializeScrollViewer()
    {
        scroll = new ScrollViewer();

        scroll.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        scroll.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Auto;
        scroll.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Auto;
        scroll.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        scroll.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        scroll.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Enabled;
        scroll.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;

        scroll.MinZoomFactor = 1;
        scroll.MaxZoomFactor = 3;
    }
```

Those are the only lines of code that affect any viewbuilding.

**Edit 2:**

My canvas doesn't fill the surrounding Grid on the left, but on the bottom.

[image]

Comment: One quick response to the above, the row definitions with stars are meant to be percentages. So `15*` actually equals `1500%`. When you use stars, I highly recommend that all the values add up to one. `<RowDefinition Height=".85*"/>` and `<RowDefinition Height=".15*" />`

Comment: Where's the polyline added? How's that being assembled?

Comment: Thank for this answer. And I found out that your code is working perfectly. But my Canvas is not wide enough to fill the surrounding grid. So your code cuts the line perfectly on the top and bottom edge but not on the left and right side. I post a screenshot in my queston.

Comment: Ok, looks like you should cap using the image, not the canvas. In my answer, replace `canvas` with the image reference. You can see there's a bit of padding on the left side of the image. That looks like dead canvas space.

Comment: The problem in this scenario is that the image is the background of my canvas. But now i know that my Polylines are build correctly and that the problem was my misunderstanding of how the parent elements of my canvas worked.

Comment: If you set a background color on your canvas / grid panels, you can visualize things better. You'll see the boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your `PointerMoved` handler should be relative to the canvas.

```
private void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvas); // <-- relative to canvas.
    var x = point.Position.X;
    var y = point.Position.Y;

    x = Math.Max(x, 0);
    y = Math.Max(y, 0);
    x = Math.Min(canvas.ActualWidth, x);
    y = Math.Min(canvas.ActualHeight, y);


    // add point to polyline...
}
```

If x/y are negative or greater than the size of the canvas, then they are out of bounds. You can either limit the point to the border of the canvas as the code above does, or you can discard the point completely.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine, theoretically. When I draw very slowly over the edge of the canvas it perfectly cuts the line. But if I draw very fast, I still can draw out of bounds. Are those events really that slow?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible. If you cap the point's x and y values, then they should never draw outside the bounds of the canvas, regardless of speed. Do you have any padding/margins/transforms affecting the drawing? Maybe post a little more code on how you're drawing the lines and I'll help you debug.

Comment: I added more details to my question. I hope this information is helpful. Maybe it's important to say that my canvas first gets it size after the grid is loaded, because i didn't find another way to get a height and width for it before the surrounding grid was build on the view.